# How to limit the data but not use a break point within an ID

Tags: oracle, where-clause, rownum

I have a sql statement to load data within Oracle which is run by a Unix script. I am using Oracle version 10.5 whereas, I have the following script which will limit the data selection to 600,000 records. I still want to limit the data but I do not want to break it up within an ID. So the break point cannot be within a dataset for any ID.

```
insert into tablea
    select ID,
               chan,
               datetime,
               sign(usage) * least(abs(usage),999999999), --target tables cannot hold usage > 9 digits to the left of decimal
               p_status,
               p_dst,
                decode(
                        substr(to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT','EST'),'yyyymmddhh24mi'),9,4),'0000',
                        substr(to_char(to_date(datetime, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') -1,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),1,8) || '2400',
                        to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT','EST'),'yyyymmddhh24mi') 
                      ),
                decode(p_dst, 60,
                decode(substr(to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT', 'EDT'), 'yyyymmddhh24mi'), 9, 12), '0000',
                        substr(to_char(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi') - 1, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') , 1, 8) || '2400',
                        to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT', 'EDT'), 'yyyymmddhh24mi')),
                        decode(substr(to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT','EST'),'yyyymmddhh24mi'),9,4),'0000',
                                    substr(to_char(to_date(datetime, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') -1,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),1,8) || '2400',
                                    to_char(new_time(to_date(datetime,'yyyymmddhh24mi'),'GMT','EST'),'yyyymmddhh24mi')))  
    from tableb
    where rownum < 600001
    order by id, chan, datetime;
```

SO I would like to add to the Where statment a clause to bring in all data for any id within the 600,000 retruned rows.

Comment: Yep... I don't understand the question.  I think the key is this: "I still want to limit the data but I do not want to break it up within an ID."  It sounds like ID could be repeated, but you don't want to break up IDs... is that right?  so if row 600,000 was ID 500 and row 600,001 was ID 500  then you would want fewer than 600,000 rows back to ID maybe 499?  So you want the rownum to be dynamic in its selection based on IDs not spanning the 60000 threshold

Answer (score 2):

First of all, determine max `rownum` within id partition

```
-- some test data
with data(id,
val) as
 (select 1, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'B'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'C'
    from dual
  union all
  select 5, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 6, 'A'
    from dual)

  select d.*, rownum, max(rownum) over(partition by id order by id) as id_max_rownum
  from data d;
```

Result:

```
ID  VAL ROWNUM  ID_MAX_ROWNUM
1   A   1       1
2   A   2       2
4   A   3       5
4   B   4       5
4   C   5       5
5   A   6       6
6   A   7       7
```

and use `id_max_rownum` to stop output at threshold:

```
-- some test data
with data(id,
val) as
 (select 1, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'B'
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'C'
    from dual
  union all
  select 5, 'A'
    from dual
  union all
  select 6, 'A'
    from dual)

select *
  from (select d.*,
               rownum,
               max(rownum) over(partition by id order by id) as id_max_rownum
          from data d) dd
 where id_max_rownum <= 4;
```

Result

```
ID  VAL ROWNUM  ID_MAX_ROWNUM
1   A   1       1
2   A   2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Frank Ockenfuss' approach, but using analytic `row_number()` instead of `rownum`. You're currently doing this in your code:

```
where rownum < 600001
order by id, chan, datetime;
```

which means you're applying the `rownum` filter to an unordered and therefore indeterminate set of rows. You might be getting lucky and the optimiser happens to return the rows in that order by chance, but if you so your luck will change if the execution plan changes. And when that happens the split won't just be in the middle of a block of IDs, there could be entire ranges of lower IDs that you never see.

The starting point is to get the row number associated with each row in your table, crucially based on the order you want to impose - this could be just by `id` but doesn't really hurt to use all three columns for consistency.

```
select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
  row_number() over (order by id, chan, datetime) as rn
from tableb;
```

Then for each row find the highest row number for the

```
select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
  rn, max(rn) over (partition by id) as max_rn
from (
  select id, chan, datetime, row_number() over (order by id, chan, datetime) as rn
  from tableb
);
```

Using xQberts example, if ID 500 spanned the 600k break point then for the rows for ID 500 would have `rn` values of, say, 599,900 to 600,050 but they would all have `max_rn` of 600,050, as the highest `rn` for any row for that ID.

So then you can filter on that:

```
select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
from (
  select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
    rn, max(rn) over (partition by id) as max_rn
  from (
    select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
      row_number() over (order by id, chan, datetime) as rn
    from tableb
  )
)
where max_rn < 600001
order by id, chan, datetime;
```

You don't need to include `rn` or `max_rn` in the final select list, just the columns you want from your original query.

And when you make an insert from that the `order by` is useless, so you would do:

```
insert into tablea(col1, col2, col3 /* other columns */)
select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
from (
  select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
    rn, max(rn) over (partition by id) as max_rn
  from (
    select id, chan, datetime, -- other columns
      row_number() over (order by id, chan, datetime) as rn
    from tableb
  )
)
where max_rn < 600001;
```

---

You can't refer directly to columns from `tableb` anywhere except the innermost query. If you include columns in that innermost select list they will be available in the next level up, which I'm already doing with `id` etc. If you have an expression then you will need to give it an alias, as I did with `rn`, and you can then use that alias at the next level up. So you will need to alias all your expressions too, e.g.:

```
select id, chan, datetime, my_usage -- other columns
from (
  select id, chan, datetime, my_usage, -- other columns
    rn, max(rn) over (partition by id) as max_rn
  from (
    select id, chan, datetime,
      sign(usage) * least(abs(usage),999999999) as my_usage,
      -- other columns/aliased expressions
      row_number() over (order by id, chan, datetime) as rn
    from tableb
  )
)
where max_rn < 600001
```

Comment: Alex, I tried your approach but I do not think row_number () is supported.

Comment: Really - what error do you get? And which version of Oracle are you using? I verified this in 11gR2 but it should work in 10g and probably 9i. Mm, your question refers to 10.5, but there isn't a version 10.5 of the DBMS. Maybe that refers to another application on top of the database, but if so, what?

Comment: It may not be the ROW_NUMBER function. i continue to get the invalid identifier error for one of my other columns.

Comment: @ThomasJ.Huber - I put 'other column' notes in each level, but maybethat's slightly misleading. Have you put your column expressions in the innermost level, with column aliases - e.g `decode(...) as some_alias` - and then only referred to the *alias* in the higher levels? You can't refer to the raw table columns from an inner query directly in an outer one.